# Nested Future in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, future

I'm new to Flutter, (comming from web and especially JS/VueJS)

I'm have a db in firebase that has a collection called edito and inside, i have different artist with a specific Id to call Deezer Api with it.

So what i want to do is first called my db and get the Id for each of artist and then put this id in a function as parameter to complete the url.

I did 2 Future function, one to call the db and one to call the api.

But i don't understand how to use one with the others in the build to get a listview with the information of the api of deezer for each data.

i'm getting the list but it's stuck in and endless loop.

All of my app will be on this nested function, is it possible to do this and call it in any widget that i want ?

here is my code, thanks

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';


class GetAlbum extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GetAlbumState createState() => _GetAlbumState();
}

class _GetAlbumState extends State<GetAlbum> {
  
  Map mapResponse;

  Future<QuerySnapshot> getDocument() async{
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("edito").get();
  }


  Future<dynamic> fetchData(id) async{
    http.Response response;
    response = await http.get('https://api.deezer.com/album/' + id);
    if(response.statusCode == 200){
      setState(() {
        mapResponse = json.decode(response.body);
      });
    }
}

  Future<dynamic> getDocut;
  Future<dynamic> getArtist;

@override
  void initState() {
   getDocut = getDocument();
   getArtist = fetchData(null);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      future : getDocut,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){
        if(!snapshot.hasData) {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }else{
          return new ListView(
              children: snapshot.data.docs.map<Widget>((document){
                print(document.data().length);
                  return FutureBuilder(
                      future: fetchData(document.data()['idDeezer'].toString()),
                      builder: (context, snapshot){
                        return Container(
                          child: mapResponse==null?Container(): Text(mapResponse['title'].toString(), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),),
                        );
                      }
                  );
          }).toList(),
          );
        }

      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplified example of making two linked Future calls where the 2nd depends on data from the first, and using the results in a `FutureBuilder`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FutureBuilder2StatefulPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FutureBuilder2StatefulPageState createState() => _FutureBuilder2StatefulPageState();
}

class _FutureBuilder2StatefulPageState extends State<FutureBuilder2StatefulPage> {
  Future<String> _slowData;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _slowData = getAllSlowData(); // combined async calls into one future
  }

  // linked async calls
  Future<String> getAllSlowData() async {
    int id = await loadId(); // make 1st async call for id
    return loadMoreData(id: id); // use id in 2nd async call
  }

  Future<int> loadId() async {
    int _id = await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () => 42);
    print('loadId() completed with: $_id'); // debugging
    return _id;
  }

  Future<String> loadMoreData({int id}) async {
    return await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () => 'Retrieved data for id:$id');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('FutureBldr Stateful'),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<String>(
        future: _slowData,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(child: Text(snapshot.data));
          }
          return Center(child: Text('Loading...'));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This avoids having to nest the `FutureBuilder` which may be error prone.

And calling future methods directly from a `FutureBuilder` is not recommended since the call could be made many times if its containing widget is rebuilt (which can happen a lot).

Comment: Just added an example of debugging an async method using print inside `loadId()` in the above example.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to add firebase in the first one but i get null for the id in the get AllSlowDAta but i got it right with the Future.delayed.

```
  // linked async calls
  Future<String> getAllSlowData() async {
    String id = await loadId(); // make 1st async call for id
    return loadMoreData(id: id); // use id in 2nd async call
  }

  Future<dynamic> loadId() async {
   //return await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () => '302127');
   await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("edito")
        .get()
        .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
           querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
           
               return  doc.data()["idDeezer"];
          });
    });
  }

  Future<dynamic> loadMoreData({String id}) async {
    http.Response response;
    response = await http.get('https://api.deezer.com/album/' + id);
    if(response.statusCode == 200){
      setState(() {
       return json.decode(response.body);
      });
    }
  }
```